# echo <option> with an array as its value

Tags: php, html

I cant seem to figure out how to get this code to work with the array that is made with mysqli_fetch_array. the amount of option values are correct but I cant get the names from the array to display. if I put in the (' ') then it breaks because it thinks it's supposed to stop there. I have tried escaping them but that gives me the same result. I know if I don't echo it out it will work but I need this to be echoed out so that it will only run if another select has a value selected.

```
<select>

<?php 

//this is just here for testing
$GLOBALS['con'] = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "Password", "database");

$Names = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Department = 'IT Support'"); 
$NameSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($Names);  
$size = count($Names); 

$I=0;
while ($I <= $size) {
    echo "<option value='$NameSelect[Full_name]'>$NameSelect[Full_name]</option>";
    $I++;
}


  ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Remove `$NameSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($Names);` and use `while ($NameSelect = mysqli_fetch_array($Names)) {` instead of `while ($I <= $size) {`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SELECT query generates a resultset of 0 to n rows. In order to consume all the rows in the resultset from your query you need to loop over the resultset

```
<?php 

//this is just here for testing
$GLOBALS['con'] = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "Password", "database");

$Names = mysqli_query($GLOBALS['con'], "SELECT * FROM user WHERE Department = 'IT Support'"); 

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($Names))
{  
    echo "<option value='$row[Full_name]'>$row[Full_name]</option>";
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: so the reason the way I did it didn't work was because the loop couldn't see the array?

Comment: Well actually you were not looping over the resultset. You were only fetching the first row of the resultset not all of the results

Answer (score 0):

```
while ($row= mysqli_fetch_array($Names)) {
    echo "<option value='$row[Full_name]'>$row[Full_name]</option>";
}
```

Comment: You still might like to correct the variable name error HINT `$row` != `$NameSelect`